# Define a static True or False for if-statement in a class method

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a class/wrapper for a training a neural-network using PyTorch. To simplify the question say the class looks something like

```py
class Wrapper:
   def __init__(self,validate,n_epochs =100_000_000):
       self.validate = validate
       self.val_score = 0

   def run(self):
       for _ in self.n_epochs:
            if self.validate:
               self.val_score  += val(self.X,self.y)
```

as you can see the check `if self.validate` has to be run 100.000.000 times, but the statement is always the same i.e it is *always* the same (it cannot suddenly switch from True to False).

I know I can write a function for each case of `validate` and then call the correct function in `run`. The issue is tho, that having, say, 3 of such "static" boolean variables would result in 9 functions in total where 99% of the code in each function is the same as the other 8 functions.

Is there a way to, somehow, define a "static" path in the "if-statement" without writing a function for each case to reduce the check-overhead? I have read some where, that some compilers tries to guess the direction of the if-statements to speed up the processes. If that's the case I assume the check-overhead of our `run` function is rather fast limited since it would start guessing correctly relative fast.

Note the order of the loops has to be as above.

Comment: In most cases, `if self.validate` is going to be a negligible fraction of the loop body's runtime anyway. Other work (like `val`) will dominate.

Comment: I have to be honest, I don't know how much it requires for Python to do such checks i.e if that's time wasting to optimize. But say it is a significant amount of time, I'm curious if it can be done (and/or how)

Comment: If you all you want is reducing 'branch operation' in cpu you're thinking unnecessarily low level. Modern cpus have smart feature to predict the path that branch op will take. Especially in this case where branch path is fixed, there's no need for further optimization in high level code. CPU architecture handles it fairly well already. Search branch predictor

Comment: To simply explain how it works, let's say your cpu ran into your 10^9 iteration and took the if clause path in the first iteration. Then in 2nd iteration it will assume the if clause path will be taken again (as usual) and move on, without waiting until the if statement gets processed. Then afterwards if it turns out that else statement should have been taken, then cpu will cry and redo it taking else clause path. But in your case it doesn't. So there's no delay whatsoever by branch ops, apart from the very first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I think you're saying, self.validate value remains the same within, at least in run() function.

Then why not change the order of if and for?

```
if self.validate:
    for _ in self.n_epochs:
        self.val_score = val(self.X, self.Y)
```

If there's some reason why you can't do so, I'd like to know the reason and maybe come up with another solution for you

Edit: ok if order has to be maintained this is another option
outside of the loop just make a local boolean variable

```
_validate = self.validate
for _ in self.n_epochs: # probably range(self.n_epochs), btw
    if _validate: 
        do_the_thing()
    else:
        break # or do_something_else()
```

or if you really just want to make the self.validate as static variable,
you need to declare it outside of init function

```
class YourClass:
    validate = False # This is static variable
    def __init__(self, something, somethingelse):
        self.validate=False # This is instance variable
```

Last edit:
move whole thing in your for loop to a function or method defined by you, and make it take the validate boolean value (or your class object) as argument.

```
def do_for_loop(self):
    if isinstance(self.validate, bool):
        if validate:
            for _ in self.n_epochs:
                # do your thing in for loop
        else:
            # do something else when validate is False
    else:
        # raise error in case self.validate is not boolean for whatever reasons
```

Comment: Yes, that is understood correctly. For each instance `self.validate` is "constant". It has to be called in the reverse order (i.e the order I specified) unfortunately

Comment: @CutePoison I edited answer. As far as I know there isn't particular keyword for static variable in Python. (for static method there is a decorator called '@classmethod')

Comment: The issue is python still has to do the check when encountering `if validate` i.e the if-statement has to evaluated each time, even though it is being evaluated to the same each time

Comment: @CutePoison Edited for that, please check

Comment: You still are doing the `if validate` check each time - thats the thing I want to avoid (if doable)

Comment: No you can call that defined function outside of the for loop , why does the for loop have to be maintained in the first place? is it in some library code or something that you can't change?

Comment: Aaah... if I understand you correctly that's exactly my argument in my question; I know I can write a function based on `self.validate` but if I have 3 of such booleans that requires 9 methods where the code is 99% the same in all of the

Comment: make a function that takes all that boolean variables and define it accordingly. I don't know how all 9 of them share 99% of code. Because for 1 example that you provided, they act completely different based on self.validate. (iterate 10000000 times vs 0).

Comment: How do they differ? is the number of iteration the only difference between 9 variations? then make a method with a parameter that represents number of iteration

Comment: Since my `run` function is way bigger than provided - the only way they would differ is 1 line actually (depending on `self.validate`) and other such booleans

Comment: Sorry for being no help, but I can't think of what exactly you want to do without concrete picture of the for loop. If it wasn't Python and instead Java, C, etc. How would you write it? I can maybe come up with corresponding methodology for Python . For instance, in Python there is 'match-case' instead of 'switch-case'. You can also write a C/C++ file and call it from Python